# Why doesn't it recognize the pattern "10?" in the following text?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I create the following text and when you want to search for the pattern "10?", it doesn't recognize anything, let's see:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-142:~$ cat > demo1.txt
10 1 101 10
1
10
101
1010111
10
1 10
1 1 1 1 10
1 1
1 0
0 10
1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-142:~$ cat demo1.txt
10 1 101 10
1
10
101
1010111
10
1 10
1 1 1 1 10
1 1
1 0
0 10
1
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-142:~$ grep "10?" demo1.txt
ubuntu@ip-172-31-30-142:~$
```

Why doesn't it recognize the pattern set in the regular expression?

[image]

Comment: See [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `?` special character is part of extended regular expressions. `grep -E "10?" demo1.txt` should return the result you're looking for.